# How to change event background colour for specific events in FullCalendar jQuery SQL ASP.NET VB Version

Tags: jquery, sql, vb.net, json, fullcalendar

I have successfully converted the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) into asp.net / VB and it works perfectly. I am struggling to change the background colour of an event based on a SQL query. I have tried many of the links on StackOverflow and on the Full Calendar Docs - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/Colors/ but I have barely any knowledge of jQuery/Javascript so this is proving very difficult for me.

I have 5 Employees and I would like each of them to have a unique colour on the Calendar. In my SQL table there is a *SalesPersonID* field for each employee. I want to change the colour based on the ID. e.g.: (I know this will not work in this scenario, it is purely for info)

```
If "SalesPersonID" = "1" Then
                      cevent.className = "Steve"
                      ElseIf "SalesPersonID" = "2" Then
                      cevent.className = "Bob"
End If
```

I have uploaded my code here - http://www.2shared.com/file/XtSva9Zp/FullCalendar_ASP_NET_VB.html

Please feel free to download and dissect it to see if you can help me!

Another guy on StackOverflow has posted this link which may help... 
http://jake1164.blogspot.com/2010/07/adding-dynamic-color-to-fullcalendar.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I narrowed it down to the fact that my database stores case-insensitive column names, so when I exported my events and tried to render them, my event objects had the property `event.classname` instead of `event.className`.  Fullcalendar only uses the camel-case version, so my css would never render.

I made a wrapper object in my php to change the lower-case property into a camel-case property and fullcalendar is now recognizing the className property.

Hope this helps.
Andy